# Estimating an infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

I want to evaluate the following limit

\begin{equation}
\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{\sqrt{i \ln(n-i)}}{n^{3/2}}
\end{equation}

I was thinking about rewriting it as Riemann sum and estimating the limit trough integrals. Does this limit exist? How would I rewrite it as a Riemann sum? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the sum as

$$ \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{i}{n}} \sqrt{\ln(n-i)} \geq \sum_{i = 0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{i}{n}} \sqrt{\ln(n-i)} \geq \sqrt{\ln(n/2)} \sum_{i = 0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{i}{n}}  $$

The sum on the far right converges to $\int_{0}^{1/2} \sqrt{x} ~\mathrm{d}x $ which is a fixed constant. But the factor $\sqrt{\ln(n/2)}$ grows unboundedly, and hence your original sequence diverges.

---

If you don't want to use the Riemann sum approximation, first notice that the summands are positive. So it is bounded below by the sum from $n/4$ to $n/2$. This means that your original sum is bounded below by

$$ \sum_{i = n/4}^{n/2} \frac{\sqrt{n/4 \cdot \ln(n/2)}}{n^{3/2}} \geq \frac{1}{8} \sqrt{\ln(n/2)} $$

and so diverges as $n\to \infty$.